# How to add an executable to PATH in Azure's Kudu?

Tags: django, python-3.x, azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I need to add the gecko driver in order to run a headless browser on Azure as part of my website, but I need to add the geckodriver to PATH (apparently I can't manually input the location of the geckodriver file in Python?)

I know I have to use the applicationHost.xdt file and add it to /home/site folder, but my Kudu page doesn't allow me to add files (I can create the file using 'touch', but I can't edit it).

This is how my Kudu page looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnbzT.jpg

This is my applicationHost.xdt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"> 
  <system.webServer> 
    <runtime xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <environmentVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <add name="geckodriver" value="geckodriverL" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />    
        <add name="PATH" value="%PATH%;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\cpu" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />    
      </environmentVariables>
    </runtime> 
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

This is the error I get from Django:

```
WebDriverException at /

Message: 'geckodriverL' executable needs to be in PATH. 

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://site.azurewebsites.net/
Django Version:     2.2.6
Exception Type:     WebDriverException
Exception Value:    

Message: 'geckodriverL' executable needs to be in PATH. 

Exception Location:     /antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start, line 83
Python Executable:  /opt/python/3.7.4/bin/python3.7
Python Version:     3.7.4
Python Path:    

['/opt/python/3.7.4/bin',
 '/home/site/wwwroot',
 '/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/opt/python/3.7.4/lib/python37.zip',
 '/opt/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7',
 '/opt/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/opt/python/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Fri, 18 Oct 2019 14:39:59 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

As I known, according to the Kudu wiki page [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox), due to the [Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions), you can not use anything with GDI that include headless browsers like Chrome with Blink and Firefox with Gecko.

To fix it, please switch to use Azure VM or Azure WebApp on Linux (it's based on Docker).